# Let $R$ be a ring with 1 and N be a submodule of R-module M. If $M$ is free of finite rank, is $M/N$ necessarily free of finite rank?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $R$ be a ring with 1 and N be a submodule of R-module M. If $M$ is free of finite rank, is $M/N$ necessarily free of finite rank?

My idea: 
No. Consider $R  = M = Z_6$ and $N = 2Z_6 = \{2,4\}$. $Z_6/2Z_6 = \{0 +2Z_6 , 1+2Z_6 , 3+2Z_6 , 4+2Z_6 \}$. Since $|Z_6/2Z_6| = 4 \neq |R^k| = |6^k|$, $Z_6/2Z_6 \ncong R^k$, hence, it is not free.

Comment: Looks good. You can also start with $\mathbb Z$ and note that $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ cannot be a free $\mathbb Z$-module since it's finite.

Comment: It's not true as long as $R$ is not a field. Since then there exists an ideal $I$ of $R$ which is neither $0$ nor $R$, and $R/I$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: @AymanHourieh what do u mean by "it's finite". Is $Z/2Z$ finite? The reason why I don't use Z is because I can't use the similar argument since they are countably infinite (I think).

Comment: A non-empty direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z$ must be infinite, right? Since $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is finite, it cannot be free.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Let $R = \mathbb Z$. A non-empty direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z$ is infinite. Since $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is finite, it cannot be free.